# Amplify Graphql appsync data return illogic bug

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

When I create an item, the item has created and I can get the item by id but when i get the list items doesn't  contain the item created.

```
type Order @model @searchable{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  ref: String!
  user: User @belongsTo
}

// first query works!!
query MyQuery {
  getOrder(id: "idxamplee") {
    id
    ref
  }
}

//second query not work
query MyQuery {
  listOrders() {
    items {
      id
      ref
    }
  }
}
```

amplify appsync dynamodb synchronization
[schemaUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEjZP.png)

Comment: Can you share the schema for both `getOrder` and `listOrders`?

Comment: this is the schema https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEjZP.png